# How to get full name of the YouTube video after search a video using python?

Tags: python, youtube, urllib, python-re

```
import urllib.request
import re
search_keyword ="music"
search_song_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_keyword)
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", search_song_url.read().decode())
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0]
str(url)
print(url)
```

From this code, I get the proper URL of youtube video but I want the full name of the video. I had tried so much but I unable to find the full name of the video.

**Please help me to get the full name of the video.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get the html of the url you just got. Then use `lxml` to make it a lot easier.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import lxml
from lxml import etree

search_keyword ="music"
search_song_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_keyword)
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", search_song_url.read().decode())
url = str("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])

youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
video_title = youtube.xpath("/html/head/title")
print (video_title[0].text)
```

Works perfectly for me.